Can a CH395 chip communicate with another CH395 chip via lines TXP, TXN, RXP, RXN without using a transformer?
I have a project for which I need to implement a test equipment, and for testing the Ethernet chip I came up with this idea (look at image). Can I connect these two chips to each other directly using the TXP, TXN, RXP, RXN lines? If so, how exactly?
For example:
TXP -> RXP,
TXN -> RXN,
RXP -> TXP,
RXN -> TXN?
And what are the difficulties? The chips are connected within the same power circuit. I would be very grateful for links or files where I can read more about similar projects and their problems.

Thus I plan to test both the chip and the situation if the RJ45 connector, which is on the test board, is not soldered. Won't this be over engineering? I think not, since this is a necessary step towards automated testing. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Documentation - static.chipdip.ru/lib/592/DOC047592657.pdf

But what kind of connector you have? Is your connector a MagJack which includes the Ethernet transformer, or do you have a separate transformer and a plain modular jack connector?

I'm going to connect these two chips bypassing the transformer, directly. One board is testing, the second one is the one being tested, they will be connected via pogo pins.

The data sheet does not have enough details about electrical specifications if it will work when two chips are direcly connected together.
Usually, TX pins and RX pins are allowed a different DC bias value so it might not work. In practice, almost always there is a need to remove the DC bias between TX and RX sides. In this case though, both the TX and RX in the data sheet are biased to 3.3V, but it is unknown how the bias currents end up as voltages.
In a real Ethernet circuit, this DC removal between two chips is done with an Ethernet transformer. Sometimes in an application where the chips and their environment is known, such as an internal link on a PCB, this AC coupling may be done with capacitors. But the chips and the circuit between chips need to support capacitive coupling if some special DC biasing arrangements are required, so not all chips support capacitor AC coupling. Your chip has no mention of this. Sometimes the chip output drivers need to be put into a mode which supports AC coupling, and the link may need to be forced to 100Mbps only, as the chips may not support 10Mbps with capacitor coupling.
So the answer to if it works is unknown based on the information. You can try it yourself or see if someone answers they have tried it and it worked. But it might work but poorly. You need to ask from the manufacturer if such a configuration is supported and how, but unless you buy these in thousands, you may not receive support from the manufacturer.
The best method to get it working is to have a board with MagJack and pogo pins then, and connect it anywhere you want with standard Ethernet cabling, like to another board with MagJack on pogo pins.
